# Step into C DLL from WCF service while debugging

Tags: wcf, debugging, vba, com, mfc

I have made a WCF Service Library projects. I added a reference of a c++ DLL . The Methods exposed by the WCF Service Call the c++ DLL functions. The Client is written in VBA(excel) 
I can not Step into the C++ code whole debugging. Can someone guide me ?

Comment: What seems to be the problem? You can't step into your C++ code or you can't step into MFC code?

Comment: C++ DLL ! I cant step into c++ DLL

Comment: We need more information to identify the  problem. Debug info is typically stored in pdb files and these need to be present and their location known in order to debug an external dll. Is your C++ dll code part of the same solution? Where do you output the pdb file to?

Comment: I fixed it. Added the C++ project to the same solution of WCF Service and it worked :)

Comment: That is one way to do it, but not the only one. Unifying the solutions (probably) made VS output the pdb files to the same output folder, hence VS was able to find the pdbs during debug. But if for some reason you don't want them to be part of the same solution, you just need to tell VS where the pdb file and source files are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. Added the C++ project to the same solution of WCF Service and it worked